# Android JUnit test BroadcastReceiver fails on abortBroadcast()

Tags: android, junit, broadcastreceiver

I'm starting to write tests for my Android application. It works OK for most of the application but I have a BroadcastReceiver for handling incoming sms, that receiver in turn calls `abortBroadcast()` in some cases. This little call causes the test case to fail with following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call while result is not pending
at android.content.BroadcastReceiver.checkSynchronousHint(BroadcastReceiver.java:772)
at android.content.BroadcastReceiver.abortBroadcast(BroadcastReceiver.java:689)
```

My test case looks like this for now:

```
public void testOnReceive() {
    Optional<byte[]> mockSmsWrapper = TestUtils.createMockSms(getContext(), sender, body);

    if (mockSmsWrapper.isPresent()) {
        SmsReceiver receiver = new SmsReceiver();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("pdus", new Object[] { mockSmsWrapper.get() });
        intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");      
        receiver.onReceive(getContext(), intent);

        //TODO: Verify results!
    }
}
```

I wonder if it's some problem with `Context`, some data not set to intent(hence `Call while result is not pending`) or if it's even possible to test `abortBroadcast()`?

Should also add that my TestClass extends `AndroidTestCase`.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am facing a very similar problem.

Comment: @MarkSmith, no not really. However I came up with a workaround which works for my needs. The workaround is to create the intent with an action ex. `new Intent(ACTION_SKIP_ABORT_BROADCAST)` then in my receiver I read out the action of the intent and if it equals to `ACTION_SKIP_ABORT_BROADCAST` then the call `abortBraodcast()` is skipped.
This is of course only for test purposes and maybe not the best solution but it works.

Comment: Thanks. I came up with a similar workaround: try/catch the IllegalStateException, since there's nothing I can do about it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your result is because of calling directly onReceive method.

Instead, you should do the following :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
intent.putExtra("pdus", new Object[] { mockSmsWrapper.get() });
intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,intent ,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
try {
    pendingIntent.send(0);
} catch (CanceledException e) {
    Log.e(YourClass.class.getSimpleName(), android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(e));
}
Thread.sleep(2000);
//Verify result
```

Comment: I've tried your solution now, and getting no error but it seems like my receiver is not beeing invoked, is there something more to this that I miss?